# Long press for non touch devices Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, long-press

I have been developing an app for Win 8. The app uses long press. It all works fine on touch devices. But now I realised something else, the long press does not work in non touch device. When I run the app on local machine, everything renders, but the long touch disappeared!

Is there no long press on the non touch PCs?

I was checking out apps on both touch tablet and non touch pc, the same app example Calendar behaves differently. The pages opening up on click/touch of a date is different in both devices? How to they do this? Maintain different code??

I need long press on my app. How do i get it run on the non touch pc? The right click of mouse brings up the navigation bar!! I need to write the same code in both holding and pointer events??

Now what to I do!
(panic!)

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate this process by using a timer and both PointerPressed and PointerReleased events.

and you can create simple timer like this

```cs
private bool _isTimerActive = false;
private int _timeInMS = 0;
private const int Delay = 1500; // wait for 1.5 sec

private async void StartTimer()
{
    _isTimerActive = true;

    while (_isTimerActive)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
        _timeInMS += 10;
        if (_timeInMS > Delay)
        {
            _holdingAction(null, null); // Do the suitable action after holding for 1.5 secounds
            StopTimer();
        }
    }
}

private void StopTimer()
{
    _isTimerActive = false;
    _timeInMS = 0;
}
```

then you have to add the event handler for every button in .cs, as button control wont allow PointerPressed and PointerReleased events to fire.

like that:

```cs
MyButton.AddHandler(PointerPressedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(Button_PointerPressed), true);
MyButton.AddHandler(PointerReleasedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(Button_PointerReleased), true);
```

finally, you can use delegate to define the action for every button

```cs
private delegate void HoldingAction(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e);
private HoldingAction _holdingAction;

// your Long-press event 
private void Button_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Your awesome code here.
}

private void Button_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StartTimer();
    _holdingAction = Button_Holding;
}

private void Button_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StopTimer();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if I have a `Button_Click` for a `Button` and I also need to hook-up a long-click on it? i tried your answer, but it seems the `PointerReleased` handler is not being invoked at all. Any suggestions?